# PostgreSQL Syntax Error When Calling From C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have this Stored Procedure in PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION USP_IT_GetUserPerGroup(groupid int)
RETURNS TABLE (
    id int,
    fullname character varying(100))
AS  
$$
    SELECT      U.id,
                U.fullname
    FROM        group_users GU
    INNER JOIN  users       U
        ON  GU.user_id = U.id AND GU.group_id = groupid
    ORDER BY    lastname
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
STABLE;
```

And C# Code as follow.

```
NpgsqlConnection    _PSql = new NpgsqlConnection ( connectionString );
NpgsqlCommand       cmd = new NpgsqlCommand ( );

cmd.Connection  = _PSql;
cmd.CommandText = "USP_IT_GetUserPerGroup";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandTimeout  = 300;
cmd.Parameters.Add ( “groupid”, 11);

_PSql.Open ( );

NpgsqlDataAdapter   pSqlAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter( cmd );
DataSet             ds = new DataSet ( );       

pSqlAdapter.Fill ( ds );
_PSql.Close ( );
```

But whenever I run the code, it will throw an exception :

```
ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near ")"
```

Apparently the C# runs the SQL request via this SQL Syntax:

```
select * from USP_IT_GetUserPerGroup(11) as()
```

Which prompted the error.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with postgresql but is `as` needs `()` as a syntax?

Comment: Your code looks OK, I think you need to find out why `as()` coming in your code

Comment: @WingedPanther . Thanks, actually I've been investigating this error for the past 3 hours now ( and still do ). As of now, I still don't have the solution.